# Matlab scatter diagram

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I have two columns of data, x and y, how can I make a ‘thermodynamic diagram’ with matlab? I want the z-axis to represent the intensity of the dots, like below figure.

[image]

The x-axis is speed, while the y-axis is torque. I want to construct a heatmap like this figure, but with dots:

[image: dots]

I tried using the imagesc function, but I didn't get what I wanted.
Example code:

```
x = rand(1373,1);
y = rand(1373,1);
z = rand(1373,1)*50;
scatter(w_mot,T_mot,z,'filled');
[Xi,Yi] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,1000),linspace(0,1,1000));
SI = scatteredInterpolant(w_mot,T_mot,z);
Ci = SI(Xi,Yi);
```

Comment: If you want the color of each dot to represent its _z_ value, you just need something like `scatter(x,y,20,z,'filled')` in your example, where `20` is the desired dot size. It there are too many dots you may prefer a 2D-histogram as in the link by @beaker

Answer (score 0):

The solution/example answers your question regarding the `scatter`-plot function in combination with a `colormap`, under the assumption that three inputs `x,y,z` or speed, torque and efficiency are known. I.e. the values below are for visualization purposes only.

```
x = randn(1373,1);   % using Normally distributed random numbers instead of uniformly
y = randn(1373,1);

z = sqrt(sum([x.^2 y.^2],2));   % calculate "density"
z = 1 - z./max(z);  % has to be normalized to 0...1

% cf. doc colormap
cmap = colormap("turbo");

% calculate a index for the color (depending on the value of normalized z)
% and ensure minimum has index 1 not zero
colIdx = max(floor(z * length(cmap)),1);

figure
scatter(x,y,20,cmap(colIdx,:),"filled")
```

[image: Output]

For different colormaps cf. [MathWorks doc](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html)